# Dictionary Ordering not correct key:value

Tags: python

I always get my dictionary disordering the data , what I'm doing wrong here ?

```
data={
'1': '1',
'2': '2',
'3': '3',
'4': '4',
'5': '5',
'6': '6',
'7': '7',
'8': '8',
'9': '9',
'10': '10',
'11': '11'
}
print data
```

**Result:**

```
{'11': '11', '10': '10', '1': '1', '3': '3', '2': '2', '5': '5', '4': '4', '7':'7', '6': '6', '9': '9', '8': '8'}
```

What do I have to do to get it in the right order?

PS : that list was just an example my list type is more complicated : 
data={ 'str1': 'str2', 'str3': 'str4', 'str5': 'str6' ....} how can i keep them in order like i write them in the first place ? 
with the key:value format

Comment: I recommend to read the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (emphasis mine): *"It is best to think of a dictionary as an **unordered set** of key: value pairs, "*

Comment: Where did you get the idea that Python dictionaries are ordered? Did you try running a Google search with "Python" plus your question's title?

Comment: And why does this useless zero-research question have three upvotes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python don't know anything about order. You can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead!

Comment: that was just an example , my list type is data={
'str1': 'str2',
'str3': 'str4',
'str5': 'str6' .... 
how can i keep them in order like i write them in this case ?

Comment: Like this `OrderedDict([('str1', 'str2'), ('str3', 'str4'), ...])`.

Comment: that's correct thanks a lot mate , just one last problem , this dict is for requests payload so it have to me `'1': '1',
'2': '2',
'3': '3'` when apply OrderedDict like you mention it works fine but with this type of dict i got this error : `    '1': '1',
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @FreeSteampowresGames,  you pass tuples of key value pairs as cdonts has shown you to an OrderedDict not `key:value`

Comment: ah ok , so how i can get my key:value order correct ?

Comment: @FreeSteampowresGames, pass the tuples in the order you want the key/values to appear

Answer (score 0):

Use OrderedDict to keep the items in the same order that you wrote them in the source file (or inserted them):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict([
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    ('3', '3'),
    ('4', '4'),
    ('5', '5'),
    ('6', '6'),
    ('7', '7'),
    ('8', '8'),
    ('9', '9'),
    ('10', '10'),
    ('11', '11'),
  ])
print data
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'), ('6', '6'), ('7', '7'), ('8', '8'), ('9', '9'), ('10', '10'), ('11', '11')])
```

Although the output doesn't look like a normal dict in this case, the "data" variable will still behave like a normal dict when you iterate over it or index into it.

Comment: and how i order key:value ?

Answer (score 0):

first you can represent your data in the following way, for the program recognize the characters between '' as the *keys* and the others as the *values*:

```
data={
'1': 1,
'2': 2,
'3': 3,
'4': 4,
'5': 5,
'6': 6,
'7': 7,
'8': 8,
'9': 9,
'10': 10,
'11': 11
}
```

Now you could apply the example in the book [pythonlearn](http://do1.dr-chuck.com/py4inf/EN-us/book.pdf) page 122 to show your data ordered by value. It is used a simple *for loop* to append the dictionary items to a list and then sorted them by value.

```
l = list()
for key, val in data.items() :
    l.append( (val, key) )
l.sort()
print l
for key, val in l:
    print key, val
[(1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'), (4, '4'), (5, '5'), (6, '6'), (7, '7'), (8, '8'), (9, '9'), (10, '10'), (11, '11')]
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
11 11
```

Comment: you can omit any of the **print** according to the way you wnaat to show the result.

Comment: and how i order key:value ? 
keep getting the error : `    l.append( (val ':' key) )
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It could be the Python version, I work with 3.3 so maybe you just need to change the 'l.append( (val, key) )' for l.append(val, key), look that is a Syntax error. You can write just one of the **print** lines  according to the way you need your data to show up.

Answer (score -1):

```
    d={
    '1': '1',
    '2': '2',
    '3': '3',
    '4': '4',
    '5': '5',
    '6': '6',
    '7': '7',
    '8': '8',
    '9': '9',
    '10': '10',
    '11': '11'
    }


    from collections import OrderedDict

    od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

    print(od)
```

OrderedDict([('1', '1'), ('10', '10'), ('11', '11'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'), ('6', '6'), ('7', '7'), ('8', '8'), ('9', '9')])

Comment: sorted order is not the same as insertion order, an OrderedDict keeps the keys in the order you add then not in sorted order

Comment: person asking the question wanted to preserve the order that was in his data. That data was sorted that is why i have used sort before inserting data into Orderded dict.

Comment: If you look at the comment to the answer about you will see that sorting is not what the OP wants, on another note your order is wrong as your are sorting *lexicographically* i.e `"2" > "10"`